# Extending a record type with another record type in F#

Tags: f#, record

I have two record types:

```
type Employee = {
        Id:          string
        Name:        string
        Phone:       string
}
    
type AuditLog = {
    PerformedBy: string
    PerformedOn: string
}
```

Following are instances of the record types:

```
let emp = {
    Id = "123"
    Name = "Abc"
    Phone = "999"
}

let log = {
    PerformedBy = "234"
    PerformedOn = "1/1/1"
}
```

Is there any way to combine the fields of these two instances to create a new record/anonymous record type like the following?

```
let combined = {
    Id = "123"
    Name = "Abc"
    Phone = "999"
    PerformedBy = "234"
    PerformedOn = "1/1/1"
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records

Comment: You can search "F# record inherit" here on SO for a great number of answers revolving around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In F# record types are not inheritable or combineable in other ways.
The only thing you can do to get a type with the combined fields is

1. to **explicitly create a new record** that has no relation to the existing 2 types
2. create such type **anonymously**, @JL0PD pointed to the docs for anonmyous types. Anonymous types can be very helpful in some situations, but explicit types are the better choice - make code more readable - in most situations.
3. create a record that has 2 fields with the 2 types, which is not really what you are looking for.

Some languages like Typescript have **intersection types** where you can define a type as having the fields of a set of other types (since the fields of the created type are the *union* of the combined types, "*intersection*" sounds strange for my taste). I guess you are looking for that, but that is not available in F# and most languages.